# asp.net: How to get the URL of another page in my application?

Tags: c#, asp.net

*Using asp.net classic with C#*
Say I have two pages, one.aspx and two.aspx (C# classes `One` and `Two`)

In One.Page_Load(), I want to redirect to two.aspx

I've been doing Response.Redirect("/two.aspx"), which of course works, but then I have the magic value hardcoded, which I'd prefer not to have. Not a big deal in this simple example, but my app has >20 pages, and that creates MANY such magic values.

What I really want to do is `Response.Redirect(Two.Url)` where Url returns something like "two.aspx".
(Ultimately, I'd have Url be an abstract on my Master, but let's start simple)

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this programmatically, at run time?
`Url` could be a static, or instance prop, or a method, and/or could take a Request arg, or really any of the "usual" options. I just need the other page-object's base URL :)

Comment: Traverse the directory(ies) for a file with a name containing 'two' and get the full file name.

Comment: There's not really an asp.net "classic". It looks like what you are referring to is asp.net WebForms. ASP classic is not .net and generally based around vbscript.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
    public static class Pages
    {
            public   const string One = "/t1.aspx";
            public   const string Two = "/t2.aspx";
            public   const string Three = "/t3.aspx";
    }
```

then, refer using

```
    var url = Pages.One;
```

?

Somewhere page urls will need to be hardcoded. Either in class, struct, resource file, or web.config

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Yeah, I could do that, or better yet have each class have it's own const string, but those solutions are just moving magic values from one place to another. I'm really wanting to do it programmatically: Two is coded in two.aspx.cs, so something somewhere knows the filename, sort of like __FILE__ in C++.

Comment: `Directory` knows the file names.

Comment: @dlchambers - and how do one knows that two.aspx is indeed the page to be redirected to? Yes, you can read directory to get file names (given permissions), then? (and FILE in C++ is just a stream). You meant to be able to read content of two.aspx.cs, and see if it contains "magic value"?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BasePage : Page
{
    public virtual string GetVirtualUrl()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void PageRedirect<T>() where T : BasePage, new()
    {
        T page = new T();
        Response.Redirect(page.GetVirtualUrl());
    }
}

public partial class OnePage : BasePage
{
    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        // Redirect to two.aspx
        PageRedirect<TwoPage>();
    }
}

public partial class TwoPage : BasePage
{
    public override string GetVirtualUrl()
    {
        return "~/two.aspx";
    }
}
```